# Android Room ksp processing does not cope with nullability correctly

Tags: android, android-room, kotlin-symbol-processing

My android application has the following room dao function

```
@RawQuery
@Transaction
abstract suspend fun queryOneOrNone(query: SupportSQLiteQuery): TEntity?
```

kapt generates the following java code:-

```
@Override
  public Object queryOneOrNone(final SupportSQLiteQuery query,
      final Continuation<? super MyEntity> $completion) {
    final CancellationSignal _cancellationSignal = DBUtil.createCancellationSignal();
    return CoroutinesRoom.execute(__db, true, _cancellationSignal, new Callable<MyEntity>() {
      @Override
      @Nullable
      public MyEntity call() throws Exception {
        __db.beginTransaction();
        try {
          final Cursor _cursor = DBUtil.query(__db, query, false, null);
          try {
            final MyEntity _result;
            if (_cursor.moveToFirst()) {
              _result = __entityCursorConverter_persistenceStorageMyEntity(_cursor);
            } else {
              _result = null;
            }
            __db.setTransactionSuccessful();
            return _result;
          } finally {
            _cursor.close();
          }
        } finally {
          __db.endTransaction();
        }
      }
    }, $completion);
  }
```

Where as ksp generates this:-

```
public override suspend fun queryOneOrNone(query: SupportSQLiteQuery):
      MyEntity? {
    val _cancellationSignal: CancellationSignal? = createCancellationSignal()
    return execute(__db, true, _cancellationSignal, object :
        Callable<MyEntity?> {
      public override fun call(): MyEntity? {
        __db.beginTransaction()
        try {
          val _cursor: Cursor = query(__db, query, false, null)
          try {
            val _result: MyEntity
            if (_cursor.moveToFirst()) {
              _result =
                  __entityCursorConverter_persistenceStorageMyEntity(_cursor)
            } else {
              error("The query result was empty, but expected a single row to return a NON-NULL object of type <MyEntity>.")
            }
            __db.setTransactionSuccessful()
            return _result
          } finally {
            _cursor.close()
          }
        } finally {
          __db.endTransaction()
        }
      }
    })
  }
```

and my application fails with....

```
"The query result was empty, but expected a single row to return a NON-NULL object of type <MyEntity>."
```

is this a ksp issue?
or have i made a mistake in my application?

by adding:-

```
ksp {
    arg("room.generateKotlin", "false")
}
```

to my gradle i can mitigate this error, however it would be prefferable to have ksp generate kotlin.